# how does shell run sh scripts?

Tags: c, linux, shell, process

We know that each time a user runs a program by typing the name of an executable object file to the shell, the shell creates(use `fork`) a new process and then loads(use `execve`) and runs the executable object file in the context of this new process.

Below is my understanding of how a shell works internally, please correct me if I was wrong:

> Commands such as `ls`, `cat` etc are executable objects (source file written by C) are in `/bin/` directory. for example, when a user type in bash shell `ls` to list files and directories, the bash shell inteprets `ls` command and fork a child process to run `ls`

Q1-Is my understanding correct?

Q2-if my understanding is correct, then when a shell run .sh script file which is:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "what is your name?"
read name
```

so the shell forks two child processes for `echo` and `read`, then how does these two processes communicate with each other? I mean how does the return output of `echo` process get passed to `read` process?

Comment: It doesn't.  `echo` runs and produces output.  Then the shell tries to read a line from the input stream.  In many cases, the output is being written to a terminal, and the input is being read from that same terminal.  As the user, you see the output of the echo on the terminal while the shell is waiting for input.

Comment: @WilliamPursell OK, so commands are executable objects (source file written by C), is it correct?

Comment: Not necessarily.  C source files can be used to generated executable files.  Not all commands are executable files.

Comment: A commandscan also be a built-in command in the shell, an alias, a function or a shell script or other script.

Comment: @amjad : Depends on the shell, of course. For `ls`, an executable has to be used when your use a (POSIX) shell, while is for instance an internal command in bash or zsh. `read` is an internal command inside shell, bash and zsh, but of course you can create a subshell explicitly to run it in a separated process. Since you don't use a pipe, the stdout of `echo` goes where your file descriptor 1 points to; by default to your terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my understanding correct?

Generally, yes. But the executable file not necessarily is in `/bin/`. A file named `ls` is searched in paths specified inside `PATH` environment variable and the match is used. The file can be in `/usr/bin` `/usr/sbin` `/usr/local/bin` etc.

And `ls` may be a builtin. Or a function. Or an alias.

> so the shell forks two child processes for echo and read

And this is where a "built-in" comes in. A built-in is an internal part of the shell handled internally by the shell. There is no `fork`, just some internal code is run and that way it can modify the environment variables. `echo` not necessarily is a builtin, it only outputs data. But `read` has to be handled specially and most probably is a builtin for it to modify `name` variable (there is no requirement for read to be builtin, it may not be, but usually shell writers solve this problem by just making `read` a builtin).

On `bash` you can check the type of command with `type`. Ex. `type echo` shows `echo is a shell builtin`.

> I mean how does the return output of echo process get passed to read process?

It doesn't.

You may want to read [posix Command Search and Execution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_01_01).